# Why does the output show that pool is closed multiple times when it is actually processing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

Why does the output show that pool is closed when it is actually processing?

Is the `res.get()` a blocking operation which prevents multiprocessing?

Why does it print `Now the pool is closed and no longer available` 5 times?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError
import time
import os

def f(x):
    time.sleep(5)
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # start 4 worker processes
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool: 
        for i in range(5):
            # evaluate "f(20)" asynchronously
            res = pool.apply_async(f, (20,))      # runs in *only* one process
            print(res.get())

    
# exiting the 'with'-block has stopped the pool
print("Now the pool is closed and no longer available")
```

Output:

```
Now the pool is closed and no longer available
Now the pool is closed and no longer available
Now the pool is closed and no longer available
Now the pool is closed and no longer available
400
400
400
400
400
Now the pool is closed and no longer available
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python's [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) module, when a new process is created, it imports the `__main__` module*. Basically it runs the same file that was passed to the main thread, but any `if __name__ == '__main__':` blocks will fail because `__name__` will be something else. Then it passes which function to call and what arguments to call it with via [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Basically when you call `with Pool(processes=4) as pool:` the 4 child processes each start up and execute the print statement.

The answer to your second question "Is the res.get() a blocking operation" is yes. You should submit all the work to the processing pool to allow it to get started before waiting for results.

Moving your print statement and separating the work submission from the result retrieval might look something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError
import time
import os

def f(x):
    time.sleep(5)
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # start 4 worker processes
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        future_results = []
        for i in range(5):
            # evaluate "f(20)" asynchronously
            future_results.append(pool.apply_async(f, (20,)))
        #get results after submitting all work
        for res in future_results:
            print(res.get())

    #move this inside "if __name__ == '__main__':" so it isn't executed in child processes.
    # exiting the 'with'-block has stopped the pool
    print("Now the pool is closed and no longer available")
```

*on Unix it does things a little differently. This is the difference between Spawn and Fork referred to in the documentation.

Comment: Does `res.get()` have to be inside the `with` block? Does it make any difference if it is placed outside the `with` block?

Comment: @variable kind of... `AsyncResult` is fed its results by a thread of the main process handled by the pool. When the end of the `with` block is reached (immediately if you don't wait for results), the pool is terminated (even if it's still doing work) and this thread is stopped, so the result will never be set. Calling `get` with a timeout will simply wait for the timeout and then raise a `TimeoutError`. You need some way to "wait" for the results to all be processed before exiting the `with` block.

Comment: An interesting use case for this behavior might be wanting to get as much work done as possible in a fixed amount of time. You could submit a bunch of work, then `time.sleep()` for a fixed amount of time, and then outside the `with` block check how much of it was completed.